# Applying conditional formatting in unusual table situation

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a datasheet form based on the following query, which is a union of several data sets that have been pivoted to give columns by date:

```
+-------------+------------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| statusType  |    valueType     | 8/1/2013 | 9/1/2013 | 10/1/2013 |
+-------------+------------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| design      | actual           |        3 |        6 |         7 |
| design      | target           |        4 |        5 |         4 |
| design      | cumulativeActual |       60 |       66 |        67 |
| design      | cumulativeTarget |       50 |       55 |        54 |
| development | actual           |       10 |       12 |         2 |
| development | target           |       10 |        8 |         8 |
| development | cumulativeActual |       30 |       42 |        44 |
| development | cumulativeTarget |       40 |       48 |        56 |
+-------------+------------------+----------+----------+-----------+  ...
```

I want to set conditional formatting on the "actual" values in each date column so that colors are set for each value as follows:

- actual >= target: green
- actual = 51-99% of target: blue
- actual < 50% of target: red

So, e.g., the "design actual" value for 8/1 would be blue, and the "development actual" values for 9/1 and 10/1 would be green and red respectively.

I can iterate through the date controls setting their conditional formatting as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim ctrl As Control
Dim tb As TextBox


For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If IsDate(ctrl.Name) Then
        Set tb = ctrl
        tb.FormatConditions.Add 'not sure what to put here
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I don't understand what I should put in the arguments for `FormatConditions.Add` here; for a given `statusType`/`actual`/date value, how would I fetch the corresponding `statusType`/`target`/date value so as to compare them for setting the formatting?

Note that this form is read-only, so maybe it doesn't have to be conditional--maybe I could just assign static colors to the values according to the above rules whenever the form is loaded.

ADDITIONAL EXPLANATION: What I'm trying to do, basically, is color values in one row according to how they compare to values in the same column in another row.  E.g. with the "8/1/2013" column, comparing the "design|actual" value of 3 with the "design|target" value of 4 to determine what color the "design|actual" value should be.

Comment: [This post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/conditional-formatting-per-row-color-scales/) might be helpful.

Comment: So it sounds like you want conditional formatting that uses values from other rows? I'm pretty sure that's not possible. If you really want to do this I think you're going to have to use a query that gets all of your desired data into the same row, even if you don't show all of it to the user.

Comment: In your explanation your usage of "design|actual" is confusing. Your field names appear to be statusType and valueType, not "design" and "actual". I guess maybe I'm still not understanding what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear about that, sorry.  I want to apply the formatting only to rows where statusType="design" and valueType="actual".  Easy enough by using `AcExpression`, but as you said, getting values from other rows is perhaps impossible (without extensive nested DLookup that would slow the form down significantly).  I will probably go with an Excel export on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.

If you need different conditional formatting configured for each row individually, I don't think that's going to work. If you cannot setup your conditional formatting in Design View then you probably won't get it to work using code either.

In case you still want some code, here's how you do conditional formatting in code using Expressions:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim tb As TextBox
    Dim fc as FormatCondition

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If IsDate(ctrl.Name) Then
            Set tb = ctrl
            Set fc = tb.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "Me![FieldName] = ""Value""")
            fc.BackColor = 13611711
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I added some explanation above.  Yes, I'm trying to set formatting only for the date columns of the "design|actual" row.